# Auto submit off in pentaho cde

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

I am new to pentaho CDE. I have created pentaho CDE dashboard in 6.1v with few filters and charts.

I need to turn off the auto submit when I click on filters, and need to add a "submit" button which refreshes the chart with filter values.

Answer (score 2):

On your chart, turn the property 'Execute at start' to false.
Your chart should listen to a parameter (e.g. param_refresh)
Add a button and, in the click action do :

```
function() {

Dashboards.fireChange('param_refresh',somevalue);

}
```

The value by itself is not so important : fireChange, by modifying param_refresh, will trigger the execution of your chart.